# Pattern for handling with Redis multiple simultaneous requests

Tags: c#, rest, redis

A have an API that executes a query that takes 1 minute to process. If someone makes a GET request to this API, I will execute the query and save the results in Redis.

New requests to this API will use the cached data from Redis, avoiding doing this 1 minute query again.

My problem is: at 8AM, my cache is dropped because new data is available in the database. The first API request will execute the 1 minute-long query. The second request will also execute the same 1 minute-long query, since the first one hasn't finished yet and Redis is empty.

In the end, I have thousands of queries running and the database can't handle all of them, and no query can finish because the database stops to work.

Is there a known pattern to handle this?

What I'm doing to handle this is to set a flag "isQueryRunning" (thread-safe by a lock) to allow just one thread to execute per time, leaving the others waiting, but I would like to know if there are other known strategies.

Answer (score 2):

There are several strategies. The one you mentioned is valid, if somewhat basic because it won't work well behind a load balancer, as your lock is not distributed.

A common way around this is for state to be stored in a persistent store. In your case, this state flag could be stored in Redis itself. That gets you over the non-distributed lock problem.

However, this ties up the server because you're waiting on request threads. In REST it is common for an API to simply check the state and either

- return stale data (a different cached copy still available while the cache is being rebuilt) or
- return a **202 ACCEPTED** HTTP status with a **LOCATION** header that has a URI that points to the new data. A client can then poll that location. This means of course you have to code that other endpoint, which will continue to return **202** until the data is available, and then either

  - return **200** with the data, or
  - return **301** or **307** (redirects back to the original URI)

The first is very simple if stale data is an OK thing. You can simply do a "swap" in the cache (very quick) when the new data is available. (Btw, this swap is probably better than simply dropping the data altogether before replacing it).

The second, is of course, more complex, but scales well and avoids stale data as much as possible. More than just a location can be returned. You may return info such as a possible ready-time for the data (e.g. 1 minute), a value indicating how much data is retrieved (e.g. a percentage), or other status. [See here](https://restfulapi.net/http-status-202-accepted/) for example.